# For some reason selenium exported script saves in .text format instead of .js format

Tags: javascript, json, selenium

I tried to export the selenium recorded script to JavaScript Mocha. Instead of saving it as a .js file, getting .text format. Not sure how to handle this .

Comment: What steps are you taking exactly to reach mentioned outcome?

Comment: Creating a new project and recording . Then clicking on the three dots from the right  side of test name and then clicked on export . While tried to save it gave me as a .text file